# React setTimeout calling order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm trying to understand how this React component works (it is meant to delay the rendering of its children):

```
function Delayed({ children, wait = 500 }) {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");

    const timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("setTimeout", show);
      setShow(true);
    }, wait);

    return () => {
      console.log("cleanup");
      window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  });

  console.log("render", show);
  return show === true ? children : null;
}
```

It produces an output like this:

```
1. render     false
2. effect 
3. setTimeout false
4. render     true
5. cleanup 
6. effect 
7. setTimeout true
8. render     true
```

I understand the order up until the very last line. Where does the last render log comes from? The boolean is already *true* at this point, so setState shouldn't trigger a re-render, but it does somehow. I'm guessing I'm missing something very obvious.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-fire-6t380

Answer (score 1):

With `useEffect` you "*tell React that your component needs to do something **after render***" ([ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)). I added some extra logging to your code, to get the timings:

```jsx
function time(msg) {
  return '[' + new Date().getTime() + '] ' + msg
}

function Delayed({ children, wait = 500 }) {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(time("effect"));

    const timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(time("setTimeout"), timeout, show);
      setShow(true);
    }, wait);
    console.log(time("created timeout"), timeout);

    return () => {
      console.log(time("cleanup"), timeout);
      window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  });

  console.log(time("render"), show);
  return show === true ? children : null;
}
```

It outputs:

```
[1641339330296] render false
[1641339330315] effect 
[1641339330315] created timeout  16
[1641339330816] setTimeout 16 false
[1641339330818] render true
[1641339330824] cleanup 16
[1641339330825] effect 
[1641339330825] created timeout 24
[1641339331325] setTimeout 24 true
[1641339331327] render true
```

So, the timeout of the effect triggers as expected after the first `render false`, but it triggers again after the `render true`, and sets another timeout, which is unwanted. You can simply guard against this case with the `if (!show)` as below:

```jsx
function Delayed({ children, wait = 500 }) {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(time("effect"));

    if (!show) { // <--- THE CHANGE IS HERE
      const timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(time("setTimeout"), timeout, show);
        setShow(true);
      }, wait);
      console.log(time("created timeout"), timeout);

      return () => {
        console.log(time("cleanup"), timeout);
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }
  });

  console.log(time("render"), show);
  return show === true ? children : null;
}
```

Output:

```
[1641339821991] render false
[1641339822010] effect 
[1641339822010] created timeout 16
[1641339822510] setTimeout 16 false
[1641339822513] render true
[1641339822517] cleanup 16
[1641339822518] effect
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be honest, I don't want prevent this, this code is just for demonstation purposes. I still don't get that last render log. If we are in the 2nd (expected) settimeout, where `show` is already true and we set state with true again, it shouldn't trigger a render, right? So where does this last render comes from?

Comment: Hey, you are absolutely right. It is as if calling `setShow` from inside the effect function, even with the same value, triggers a rerender. I cannot explain this. One hint though, **which may also be a solution for your problem**, is that if you make the effect depend on the right things, the excessive render goes away: `useEffect(..., [setShow, wait])`